# Format string to java8 ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, date, formatting

Im having issue with formatting this string into `ZonedDateTime` object. I tried following oracle docs but I failed and I have no idea how it should be.

```
String date = "Sat Dec 01 20:56:28 CET 2018"
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu");
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
```

I get

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Sat Dec 01 20:56:28 CET 2018' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: how is failing???

Comment: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Sat Dec 01 20:56:28 CET 2018' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: By the way, this is a terrible format. Where possible, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats to exchange date-time values. The standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings.

Comment: It looks like you are parsing the string from `toString()` from an old-fashioned `Date` object? If within your reach, rather use `Date.toInstant()` for converting to a modern type since it is easier and safer. Parsing the three letter time zone abbreviation robably works when it’s `CET` but will give wrong results in many other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), to determine the human language used in translating name of month and such.

```
String date = "Sat Dec 01 20:56:28 CET 2018";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , 
        Locale.US 
    )
;

ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Comment: Wow, never thought it will be the issue. Thanks mate

Comment: Thanks Basil for your clean editing